# Google Play Services update requesting Identity permission?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, google-play-services, android-permissions

In the last realease of my app to the Play Store, a new permission was requested to user:

**Identity: find accounts on device**

This is the list of the permissions specified in my manifest, but it doesn't seems to be anything about Identity specified there.

Can anyone explain why such permission was requested on the new installation?

In my last release I upgraded to **Google Play Services** 7.8, is it possible that the new GPS implicitely requests a new permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely being added by Play Services.

See this question for more information

[More Permissions in uploaded apk than in manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646830/more-permissions-in-uploaded-apk-than-in-manifest-file/32647054#32647054)

Comment: Thanks! I was previously specifying the entire Google Play Services library in Gradle. I am now specifying only the packages I need, and the Identity permission disappeared!