# Play Store falsly reporting that AdMob is included in submitted application

Tags: android, admob

I've got an Android application that is being submitted to the Play Store.  That application is built using the same Gradle build script but has several different product flavors being built which just set properties for different application ID's and names for each different flavor.

The problem we have is that AdMob is 'not' included in the build script, but some of the build flavors that are being submitted the Play Store is reporting that AdMob was found in the application.  But other flavors (built from same build script) are accepted fine without any AdMob notification.

Has anyone seen this issue and possibly know what might be triggering it?  Besides our own internal libraries, this is what's being included in the dependencies of the build script:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile group: 'com.android.support', name: 'support-v4', version: '21.0.3'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

    // ViewPagerIndicator Library
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

I've checked the 'libs' directory but we only have 3 jar files in it that have just some included class files so there isn't any SDK's in that directory.

This is what the Play Store is reporting:
[image: Play Store Error Image]

Answer (score 2):

In your gradle build script you have:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

This means that all Google play services are included into your project (including AdMob as well).

Instead, you should include only play services that you need. For example:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0'
```

Take a look at [this guidelines](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: Thanks to both Kuffs, and cakan.  I had been searching for this but couldn't find that information on this and I'm still fairly new with Android development.  It's strange that only a couple of the builds are getting detected on this.  I'll see if we can narrow down the actual services the app is using.  As far as I know, it's just using the Map services.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Google Play Services which includes Admob.

You can exclude Admob by only referencing the Google Play Services libraries you actually require instead of the complete set.

More details here on how to do that:
[More Permissions in uploaded apk than in manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646830/more-permissions-in-uploaded-apk-than-in-manifest-file/32647054#32647054)